# Trouble using function keys to change screen brightness, sleep and adjusting keyboard backlight on ROG Zephyrus G15 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, asus, brightness, backlight

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15. I am not able to use the following keyboard action keys shortcuts(Fn+Function keys):

1. Screen brightness(Up:`Fn`+`F7` / Down:`Fn`+`F8`)
2. Keyboard backlight(`Fn`+`Up Arrow Key`)
3. Microphone mute(Dedicated button)
4. Sleep(`Fn`+`F11`)
5. Aeroplane mode(`Fn`+`F12`)
6. Touchpad deactivate/activate button(`Fn`+`F10`)

Edit:
I already tried adding `acpi_osi=` and later `acpi_osi=linux` after `quiet splash` in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but no luck, the laptop would just hang with a blank screen after showing the boot logo.

If the solution is not available, how do I **code** it myself to make it work, please give me some pointers. Thank you.

Comment: find out how to issue those commands in a terminal and then make a Ubuntu shortcut key to make them work . it might require a script for instance to increment screen brightness and not go over the max value eg sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness    .... cd /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0$ cat brightness  ;cat max_brightness ; cat actual_brightness

Comment: I went to this directory /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness. and found that the files you mentioned were there. But when I did $ sudo 52 >> actual_brightness and $ sudo 52 >> brightness, the brightness didn't change, and also permission denied message showed up. Any pointers, or can you tell what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, I came across this [asus-linux.org](https://asus-linux.org/wiki/keyboard-leds-anime/#installing) website and that had the solution. I just had to update my kernel to the latest version(5.11 as of now). I installed the latest kernel with [Mainline](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/) kernel updater software.

The screen brightness and the keyboard backlight Function keys are working now. And some other bugs were solved.

Comment: in my machine ROG G531GD, after installing stable kernel 5.11 for ubuntu 20.04, when reboot will face error "need to load kernel first". To fix: on BIOS disable secure boot and/or fast boot.